# Generated OData client libraries and OpenType properties

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata, datasvcutil

I am developing an OData server with an entity that contains OpenType properties.  Two new client projects have started: one for iOS, using [OData4ObjC](http://odata.github.com/OData4ObjC/), and the other uses the generated .Net libraries (via DataSvcUtil).

As far as I can tell -- neither support OpenType properties.  Is this true?  Perhaps I'm missing something?  Are there typical workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about the iOS one, the .NET one supports some types of use cases for open properties. If on the client you know which open properties you're going to access, you can add those to the generated classes manually (the generated classes are partial). The client will then treat them as any other property and it should work. (You might need to set the DataServiceContext.IgnoreMissingProperties=true, so that it doesn't fail if the property is not present on some instance from the server).

But a full support for open properties (as in being able to dynamically read and write whatever the server sends) is not implemented in the .NET client. You could use ODataLib to consume and produce such payloads, but it's not as easy to use (http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.OData)

Comment: OK, I feared as much.  The open properties that we use will be specified by the customer at runtime.  Thanks!